# How to exclude older versions of maven dependency and use new version of it?

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependency-management

I am working with Maven project and I have two projects, `ProjectA` and `ProjectB`. My `ProjectA` is a maven library whose pom looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.texture.partial</groupId>
        <artifactId>PartialPlatform</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5-RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.texture.transform.golden</groupId>
    <artifactId>SampleClient</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.texture.partial.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>PartialKernel</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.texture.webres</groupId>
            <artifactId>WebResPartial</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.texture.kernel</groupId>
            <artifactId>TextureServer</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.texture.kernel</groupId>
            <artifactId>Kernel</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.texture.v3jars.Houston</groupId>
            <artifactId>KernelDAL</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.texture.kernel</groupId>
            <artifactId>uKernel</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.texture.kernel</groupId>
            <artifactId>uKernelCore</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.cglib</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.texture.partial.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>ConfigWeb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.texture.partial.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>PartialWeb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.jmockit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}"/com/googlecode/jmockit/jmockit/1.7/jmockit-1.7.jar</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <instrumentation>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/test/**/*.class</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </instrumentation>
                    <formats>
                        <format>xml</format>
                        <format>html</format>
                    </formats>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

In my above pom, `PartialKernel` is bringing older version of various Spring Framework dependencies like `spring-core`, `spring-web`. It is bringing `3.2.8.RELEASE` version and I want to use latest version of those two spring framework, which is `4.1.6.RELEASE`. What  is the right way to exclude older versions of `spring-core` and `spring-web` coming from `PartialKernel` and use latest version?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

I need to use latest version since some classes are there in latest version only.

Comment: If you specify a newer version of the same artifact in any of the pom.xml involved in your project, it should automatically use those. If in doubt, your top-level pom.xml wins out.

Comment: Are you sure the two spring versions are actually compatible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There may be incompatible differences between the version of a library that a dependency requires and the one you want to use.  If you are happy to take this risk, you can use maven `exclusions` to ignore transitive dependencies.

You can exclude, for example, `spring-core` from being brought in by `PartialKernel` by adding:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.texture.partial.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>PartialKernel</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Note that you will have to do this for every dependency that brings in spring dependencies.

Now define the version of `spring-core` you want to use in the top level pom [dependency management](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management) section:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: you need to do the exclusions to remove the dependency mismatch errors you get.

Comment: Managing the version in the top-level POM resolves it everywhere -- including via transitive dependencies.  You do _not_ need the excludes in that case.  Managing the version is a strictly better alternative to excludes, since you don't run into the case of a needed dependency being missing entirely at runtime (though of course you can still run into missing classes etc. if they are absent from the managed version).  Excludes are best used when you actually want to make sure something isn't pulled in at all, in conjunction with the `bannedDependencies` rule of maven-enforcer-plugin.