# NoSuchMethodException: getProperties on jar execution

Tags: java, maven, exception, glassfish, glassfish-embedded

I have an embedded GlassFish server, which works well if I run the main file direclty from my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate). When I try to export a jar using maven and run the jar from command line, I get the following error:

```
jul 07, 2018 11:48:43 AM org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo start
SEVERE: Exception while invoking class com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication start method
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:138)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.DeployerImpl.deploy(DeployerImpl.java:129)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.DeployerImpl.deploy(DeployerImpl.java:105)
        at app.App.main(App.java:25)
```

The weird thing is that this error only occurs when I export a jar using maven. This is my pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>myArt</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>dependency/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>app.App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR with runtime dependencies so that this program can be executed from command line using java -jar command -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependency</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>app.App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.64</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/javax.json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey/jax-rs-ri -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.26-b03</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework/jersey-test-framework-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.26-b03</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers/jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
            <version>2.26-b03</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>simple-jndi</groupId>
            <artifactId>simple-jndi</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.4.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

</web-app>
```

I tried googling and I read that this is generally caused by incompatible Jersey versions (1.x vs 2.x), however, I could not find an incompatibility. Any help out there?

EDIT: Also, this is my list of exported jars (by maven dependency plugin):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to your pom:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-verbose</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

this will make it log which jar the `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` class is loaded from.

Comment: Where in the log exactly can I see which jar is used?

Comment: Try use `mvn package` in terminal of IntelliJ, it should print the information such as `loading from javax.ws.rs.core.Application from ...jar` in the terminal.

Comment: It seems to be using glassfish-embedded-all-3.1.2.2.jar, how do I change that (and what should I change it to)?

Comment: See this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738112/how-to-exclude-older-versions-of-maven-dependency-and-use-new-version-of-it

Comment: I fixed it by updating the used version of glassfish-embedded-all, thanks for your help!