# Is there a way in POM to specify a higher version for dependent package?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am using Maven to set up dependency in my app.

I am using Spring Boot **v2.1.12.RELEASE** which brings in Spring Core **v5.1.13**.

But there also a library Spring Integration **v5.1.9** (which is latest) and brings Spring Core **v5.1.11.RELEASE**

As you can see that I want Spring Integration to not resolve to **v5.1.11** of Spring Core as it has some vulnerabilities.

Is there any way to specify in POM for Spring Integration to resolve to **5.1.13** of Spring Core (instead of ***5.1.11***) ?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.12.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

*P.S I do not want to upgrade to the latest release of Spring Boot.*

Comment: technically you can of course upgrade and simply add this dependency to your pom file and update the version but I strongly discourage to do so cause this implies some other dependencies (transitive). I recommend to upgrade your spring-boot version to most recent ones 2.2.4.RELEASE...

Comment: If it resolves to 5.1.11 you are doing something wrong in your pom. Spring Boot manages the dependencies. In other words, please post your `pom.xml`.

Comment: @M.Deinum: Added the POm snapshot

Comment: You should import the spring-boot-dependencies or define Spring Boot as the parent (as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-maven)). remove the version tag for spring integration.

Answer (score 1):

Use maven exclusion tag to exclude the transitive dependency, make sure the excluded library is directly added to pom or it's pulled in by some other dependency.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
   <version>5.1.9</version>
   <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
         <version>5.1.11.RELEASE</version>
      </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

DISCLAIMER: This is just a work around solution for your immediate need, use it only when no other options are possible as managing spring managed dependencies ourself is not maintainable in long run.

Comment: If you start doing this in a spring boot app you are doing wrongly (especially when it comes to Spring boot managed dependencies).

Comment: @M.Deinum i agree with you. Spring managed dependency we should not start managing, that defeats the purpose and it's harder to maintain in long run. Yet, if a user decides to go for it as a last resort to get around his limitations due to any reason, then there is a way and that's what i tried to convey by my answer.

Comment: @M.Deinum added a disclaimer to my answer. thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

I used the recommendation in the post [Dependency Management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738112/how-to-exclude-older-versions-of-maven-dependency-and-use-new-version-of-it?rq=1) to overcome my challenge.

So I excluded the spring-core dependency from spring integration and also added the spring core library using below code

```
 <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.13.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: The fact that you need this is a clear indication that your pom has issues.

Comment: Yes, it could be because, someone who designed the POM, has not included spring-boot-starter-parent, which is little annoying.